# BitSet using more memory than it should

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bitset

I was writing code to calculate prime numbers within which I was using a `BitSet`.

When executing:

```
int count = 1_500_000_000; // 1.5 billion
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(count);
```

I get the exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

---

In my small world a `BitSet` that holds 1.5 billion entrys should roughly use:

`1500000000 / 1024 / 1024 / 8 ~= 180` megabytes of memory.

Even though I'm creating a 32-Bit program these numbers should be nowhere near any limits should they?

Comment: how much heap space do you have? Also note that it's probably closer to 250 MB (each "byte" of memory contains 6 bits in the BitSet implementation).

Comment: The code in my system is using exactly 190 MB, is there something you might be missing?

Comment: Ok that's probably it. `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` returns `259522560` which is only ~250 MB. Is that heapsize normal for a 32-Bit application?

Comment: Which JVM are you using? 250 MB  default heapsize was raised in the past if I am correct

Comment: @MangatRaiModi I'm using java 1.7 32-Bit (because of reasons ;)). So using a 64-Bit JVM will probably solve this issue

Comment: Try this: java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr HeapSize

Comment: @ParkerHalo you can run java with `-Xmx500m` to see if it makes a difference

Comment: @MangatRaiModi i did try that and it tells me my MaxHeapSize is 256 MB!

Comment: @ParkerHalo there should be no space between `-Xmx` and `500m`. Maybe you have a space there?

Comment: @assylias it works now! So it's definitely my heapsize that's too small!

Comment: @assylias you mentioned that "each "byte" of memory contains 6 bits in the BitSet implementation". I'd like to read more about that topic, but i can't find any sources to that!

Comment: @ParkerHalo I just had a quick look at the code.

Comment: @ParkerHalo but running a quick test it seems that it's only using ~180MB - my bad. But then you have the overhead of the JVM etc. so it uses a bit more than 200MB in total.

Comment: @assylias are you sure about 6 bits per byte? That would be very wastefull! But according to my understanding `BitSet` stores 64 bits in a long and uses `numBits >> 6` longs to store all bits.

Comment: @ThomasKläger no it was a mistake (see my previous comment, just above yours).